# Why print the number of Parsetree.implementation fail at ocaml compiler source code?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

This code works fine:

```
let ()=
 let filename = "/home/wk/prog/LocationTest/b.ml" in
 Location.input_name := filename ;
 let readhandle = open_in filename in
 let buf = Lexing.from_channel readhandle in
 Location.init buf filename ;
 let ast = Parse.implementation buf in
 Printf.printf "%d" (List.length ast) ;
```

the type of ast is Parsetree.structure which is "structure_item list",so I can use List.length get it's length

I use the same method to debug ocaml 4.07 compiler source code:

I change ocaml 4.07 compiler source code /driver/pparse.ml 181-183:

```
let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel ic in
Location.init lexbuf inputfile;
Profile.record_call "parser" (fun () -> parse_fun lexbuf)
```

to this:

```
let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel ic in
Location.init lexbuf inputfile;
let xx=parse_fun lexbuf in
Printf.printf "%d" (List.length xx);
Profile.record_call "parser" (fun () -> xx)
```

the parse_fun is Parse.implementation,then "make world",got error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
   but an expression was expected of type a
```

I don't know why the same way fail in this situation,Thanks!

Comment: What's the full error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, may I suggest you to not learn OCaml by looking at the compiler code base? The compiler code base is full of old idioms, subtle invariants, heavily optimised algorithms, and is quite underdocumented for a beginner. Thus, it is in general not a good place to learn if you are struggling with OCaml.

For your error at hand, the problem is that the result of `parse_fun lexbuf` is not a `structure`, but a locally abstract type `a`. This locally abstract type is constrained by the `kind` argument of `file_aux`. The type of `kind` is `a ast_kind`which is a Generalised Abstract Data Type (aka a GADT) defined as

```
type 'a ast_kind =
| Structure: structure ast_kind
| Signature: signature ast_kind
```

thus `a` may be either a structure or a signature. Those are both lists, but you need to expose this fact to the typechecker to be able able to compute the list length:

```
let len (type a) (kind:a ast_kind) (l:a) = match kind with
| Signature -> List.length l
| Structure -> List.length l
```